# What does it mean by 'cost' in CS?

Tags: terminology

I've seen the word 'cost' being used several times in describing algorithms e.g. algorithm A costs more to compute than algorithm B. What does 'cost' mean in this sense?

Comment: In _that_ sense, it means that one algorithm requires more CPU cycles to compute (so it's slower), but more often "cost" refers to difficulty of a cryptographic attack.

Comment: Then, in the latter, does a high cost refer to a more difficult encryption to decrypt?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about general terminology unrelated to cryptography.

Comment: @Maeher To be fair, we have a lot of questions like that which are open, even questions asking about the history behind naming conventions or why constructions were named such.

Comment: I'm _not_ voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a common source of confusion _even among cryptographers_ how to model costs of cryptanalytic attacks, as discussed in, _e.g._, the [Nonuniform cracks in the concrete](https://cr.yp.to/papers.html#nonuniform) paper, but I lack the time at the moment to write a detailed answer about standard metrics like RAM, NAND, and the most physically realistic (but still not perfect) area\*time or AT metric.

Comment: There's a very brief overview here: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/67931

Answer (score 2):

There is not one commonly accepted definition of "cost" in cryptography, other than the definition of "cost" in a common dictionary; this is not jargon or slang to my knowledge.

Here is the most logical definition from Merriam Webster:

> b: the outlay or expenditure (as of effort or sacrifice) made to achieve an object

I'd say that "object" is not a particular object here, it should be read as "objective".

---

Usually "cost" refers to CPU time, commonly counted using the number of CPU cycles as unit for a particular CPU.

**Depending on the context** it may also refer to memory usage requirements or even energy expenditure. For hardware it may also relay to transistor count, die size or other costly elements within chip design.

Answer (score 0):

In general it means that it's too inefficient to compute (it would take far too long).

In the context of your question it means that algorithm B is *faster* than algorithm A.